# SyntaxError: Unexpected token u or [SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input]

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, promise

this is my code i use promises

```
    var http = require("http");    
        function webFunc(req, res){
            var p = getData();
            p.then(function(data) {
                // var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
                // console.log(JSON.parse(data))
                res.send(JSON.parse(data)); 
            }).catch(function(err) {
                console.log(err);
            })
        }
        function getData(){
            var prom=new Promise (function(resolve,reject){
            http.get(url,function(res) {
                    var data = "";
                    res.on("data", function(chunk) {
                        data += chunk;
                        resolve(data);
                        return;
                    })
                    res.on("error", function(error) {
                        console.log("Got error: " + error.message);
                        reject(error);
                    });
                });
            })
            return prom;
        }
```

when i run route without set JSON.parse like this

```
 res.send(data);
```

I got half data or all data on each time run 
   if i set JSON.parse like this

```
 res.send(JSON.parse(data));
```

I got this error

```
 [SyntaxError: Unexpected token u]
    or this 
     [SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input]
```

the result of data should contain 8 objects of info like this
i did this commands

```
    console.log(data)
    console.log("typeof data",typeof data)
   i got this 
{"days":{"location":{"id":11,"name":"city","resultinfo":{"info":[{"d":"2017-02-07","tt":15,"ss":"39"
    typeof data string
```

How i can solve this problem

Comment: What does `data` contain?

Comment: can you show me console.log(data);

Comment: That's not JSON. (Details in my answer.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the data too soon. Refer to the example in [the documenation of `http.get`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback):

```
let rawData = '';
res.on('data', (chunk) => rawData += chunk);
res.on('end', () => {
  try {
    let parsedData = JSON.parse(rawData);
    console.log(parsedData);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
  }
});
```

You want to use the data on the `end` event, not on the `data` event. You're processing only *part* of the data if you resolve the project as of the first `data` event.

So (note `***` lines):

```
function getData() {
    var prom = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        http.get(url, function(res) {
            var data = "";
            res.setEncoding('utf8');              // See note below
            res.on("data", function(chunk) {      // ***
                data += chunk;                    // ***
            })                                    // ***
            res.on("end", function() {            // ***
                resolve(data);                    // ***
            });                                   // ***
            res.on("error", function(error) {
                console.log("Got error: " + error.message);
                reject(error);
            });
        });
    })
    return prom;
}
```

As [Ryan points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42086510/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-u-or-syntaxerror-unexpected-end-of-input/42086574#comment71343427_42086574), you need the

```
res.setEncoding('utf8');
```

indicated above if you want the data chunks as strings rather than as Buffers.

---

<s>Re your edit:</s>

> the result of data should contain 8 objects of info like this

The data you've quoted isn't JSON. In JSON, property names must be in double quotes. To be JSON, it would have to look like this:

```
{
    "first-days": {
        "location": {
            "id": 11,
            "loc": "city",
            "info": {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've left out bits of your example that just didn't make any sense at all, but you get the gist. More [on JSON.org](http://json.org).

*Your subsequent edit shows the real thing; what we can see of it looks like valid JSON.*

Comment: @Ryan: `http.get` doesn't handle the `Content-Type` header automatically? **sigh** :-)

Comment: Well, it’d be convenient for the best case, but maybe a little awkward for error handing. =)

Comment: @Ryan: Thanks. :-)

Comment: @maryam: I linked to an example in the original answer, and since then I've updated the answer with a copy of your code with the changes needed. (But that was a nice-to-have; the linked example was sufficient.)

Comment: so which one i have to try ?

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = "";
res.on("data", function(chunk) {
    data += chunk;
    resolve(data);
    return;
})
```

This isn’t right. The chunks should be buffers by default when no encoding is set on the stream, and you shouldn’t resolve after the first chunk.

```
var parts = [];

res.on("data", function (chunk) {
    parts.push(chunk);
});

res.on("end", function () {
    resolve(Buffer.concat(parts).toString("utf8"));
});
```

Comment: i did ur code 
var parts = [];
function getData(){
    var prom=new Promise (function(resolve,reject){
    http.get(url,function(res) {
            var data = "";
            res.on("data", function(chunk) {
                  parts.push(chunk);
            })
            res.on("end", function () {
                resolve(Buffer.concat(parts).toString("utf8"));
            });
            res.on("error", function(error) {
                reject(error);
            });
        });
    })
    return prom;
}

Comment: it is bring data but in every time i run it add same data

Comment: @maryam: If you access `url` manually through a browser, does it produce complete JSON?